# Docker: Operation not permitted on workspace directory android

Tags: android, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline for my android project using Jenkins and docker(I'm using docker file) and here's a sample of the Jenkinsfile

```
  pipeline {
    agent { dockerfile true }
    environment {
        appName = 'Yoruba Proverbs'

        KEY_PASSWORD = credentials('keyPassword')
        KEY_ALIAS = credentials('keyAlias')
        KEYSTORE = credentials('keystore')
        STORE_PASSWORD = credentials('storePassword')
    }
    stages {
      ....
    }
  }
```

The build fails at the instance when docker is trying to make a modification under the workspace directory with an operation not permitted error(FileSystemException). Here's a screenshot: [build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEBZO.png)

I have tried a few different tweaks like restarting Jenkins, restarting docker, Granting docker full disk access on my laptop but no positive result

**Edit:**
This is the content of the Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8

WORKDIR project/

# Install Build Essentials
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install build-essential -y

# Set Environment Variables
ENV SDK_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip" \
    ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk" \
    ANDROID_VERSION=30

# Download Android SDK
RUN mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME" .android \
    && cd "$ANDROID_HOME" \
    && curl -o sdk.zip $SDK_URL \
    && unzip sdk.zip \
    && rm sdk.zip \
    && mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true \
    && echo "24333f8a63b6825ea9c5514f83c2829b004d1fee" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license" \
    && yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

# Install Android Build Tool and Libraries
RUN $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
RUN $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;30.0.3" \
    "platforms;android-${ANDROID_VERSION}" \
    "platform-tools"

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of Dockerfile?

Comment: @PsyGik I've done that

Comment: I am assuming the error is due to less privilege when running Docker inside of Jenkins. Maybe try to use the same user? `args '-u 0:0' // or try to make it -u root` by passing this in the `agent` context in your Jenkinsfile